# Uncles and its parameters

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, blockchain, blocks

Is there possible that **current block** do not have **uncles**? As we know that **Main block** contain the contract information , What does **uncles holds** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there possible that current block do not have uncles?

A block *may* or *may not* contain any uncles. Specifically, a block in the main chain can contain a pointer to a list of one or more uncles. The *rate* of uncle/ommer creation - i.e. how often creation happens - is covered here: [What is the significance of uncle rate?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/317/what-is-the-significance-of-uncle-rate?noredirect=1&lq=1)

> As we know that Main block contain the contract information...

It contains a hash to the root of the state data tree. Strictly speaking the block itself doesn't contain the contract data, it just points to it.

> What does uncles holds ?

Uncle blocks hold the same data as normal blocks (e.g. transactions, which themselves bring about changes in the state data), it's just that this information didn't manage to get into the canonical main chain in time. It is no less valid though. See [What is an uncle/ommer block?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/34/what-is-an-uncle-ommer-block?rq=1)

Comment: " Block itself doesn't contain the contract data, it just points to it."  Then where do the contract data store ?

Comment: It's stored in a database, separate to the blockchain itself. If you run a full node then you download the whole of the database, as well as the actual chain. https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/8000/52