# Are two mined blocks with the same parent block both rewarded 5 ether?

Tags: mining

I've read the following document describing mining on the Ethereum network:

https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Mining

Now, the successful PoW miner of the winning block receives 5 ether. Conversely, uncles are rewarded significantly less.

Are two mined blocks with the same parent block both rewarded 5 ether? Or will one of the blocks be an uncle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us call these blocks W and L. Both blocks are rewarded 5 ether in the fork for which the block appears as part of the main ledger history. However, eventually, one of the forks will dominate (the one descending from W)-- it has more children -- and the other fork will die off (the one descending from L). If L is included as an uncle block within 6 blocks of W in the chain descended from W, then L will be an uncle and will be rewarded the amount set for uncles.

## What this looks like

Assume that W and L are mined by different miners (`w` and `l`, respectively) and both have coinbases with 0 ether. I'm using miners and their coinbases/accounts interchangeably in this answer.

#### From `w`'s perspective

`w` has 0 ether until block W and then suddenly has 5 ether -- and it stays that way -- then, shortly afterwards, `l`'s balance goes from 0 to 4.375 (or less) ether (depending on when it is included as an uncle). This remains the same until more blocks are mined or new transactions involving the accounts are made.

#### From `l`'s perspective

`w` and `l` have 0 ether until block L; at this point, `w` has 0 ether and `l` has 5 ether. At some point, the miner of L's node will sync with the network. `w`'s account will have 5 ether and, depending on whether `l`'s block has been included as an uncle, yet, the balance for `l` will go to 0 or the uncle reward amount. If it goes to 0, it can rise again once L is included as an uncle block.

Comment: Who are responsible for including blocks as uncles, and what exactly are uncles?

Comment: You can find more info on uncle blocks here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/34/what-is-an-uncle-ommer-block