# Why is there a same transaction in two blocks in Ethereum (from Cloudflare provider)?

Tags: etherscan, eth-cli

I found a same transaction appeared in two blocks according to our app log files. It results in a primary key error in the database since we used `tx.hash` for PK column.

You will see transaction `0x1f755c38f032091736b4f331f7db77a04917d962078db57efc1e8156163c68bc` in both queries' responses below. How can it?

```
eth block:get 15365119 --network 'https://cloudflare-eth.com/v1/mainnet'
eth block:get 15365121 --network 'https://cloudflare-eth.com/v1/mainnet'
```

Transaction `0x1f755c38f032091736b4f331f7db77a04917d962078db57efc1e8156163c68bc` is in both blocks `15365119` and `15365121`. While it's only in block 15365121 on [Etherscan](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x1f755c38f032091736b4f331f7db77a04917d962078db57efc1e8156163c68bc) now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug in `cloudflare-ethereum` node. You'll better look into the block's hash, not its height. Then you will notice this situation:

```
#Cloudflare Node

Block: 15365118
    hash: 0x29bc1b3921ed15e1ff5cac10e734fdd40560328fa6a4c378937cad145bbca81d
    parent: 0x44da884a8911bb9c1d5d13abc4e51599e22d9e93a18fd68be280e65223683361

Block: 15365119
    hash: 0xbe60bbd06e25905ad4ac4d673d0319b75746ae601312b730eec7d555dfcb0497
    parent: 0x29bc1b3921ed15e1ff5cac10e734fdd40560328fa6a4c378937cad145bbca81d

Block: 15365120
    hash: 0x64f54c56d61b694f56d1462d4327809e9c2aa64296100fe4c697ee3dc90d68ac
    parent: 0x64a7a42d598161339f909f5ef95e8f4c1c5f70efd4e1a3649c121b04a030d1f3

Block: 15365121
    hash: 0x8c92d1d3bf040cc24693679027ea52ec4edf8a73ee07f147353d7c25baec35f9
    parent: 0x64f54c56d61b694f56d1462d4327809e9c2aa64296100fe4c697ee3dc90d68ac


#Etherscan

Block: 15365118
    hash: 0x29bc1b3921ed15e1ff5cac10e734fdd40560328fa6a4c378937cad145bbca81d
    parent: 0x44da884a8911bb9c1d5d13abc4e51599e22d9e93a18fd68be280e65223683361

Block: 15365119
    hash: 0x64a7a42d598161339f909f5ef95e8f4c1c5f70efd4e1a3649c121b04a030d1f3
    parent: 0x29bc1b3921ed15e1ff5cac10e734fdd40560328fa6a4c378937cad145bbca81d

Block: 15365120
    hash: 0x64f54c56d61b694f56d1462d4327809e9c2aa64296100fe4c697ee3dc90d68ac
    parent: 0x64a7a42d598161339f909f5ef95e8f4c1c5f70efd4e1a3649c121b04a030d1f3

Block: 15365121
    hash: 0x8c92d1d3bf040cc24693679027ea52ec4edf8a73ee07f147353d7c25baec35f9
    parent: 0x64f54c56d61b694f56d1462d4327809e9c2aa64296100fe4c697ee3dc90d68ac
```

You see the blocks `15365118` and `15365120` are identical. But the `15365119` in cloudflares node is another block, it has the hash `0xbe60bbd0...`

This block was indeed mined: https://etherscan.io/uncle/0xbe60bbd06e25905ad4ac4d673d0319b75746ae601312b730eec7d555dfcb0497

But it was replaced or not included into the blockchain. Such blocks are called uncle (ommer) blocks. Related question: [What is an uncle/ommer block?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/34/what-is-an-uncle-ommer-block)

So, for some reason, `cloudflare-ethereum` returns that uncle block as a valid block at height `15365119`, but it is not true. So you'll better write to Cloudflare's support explaining the bug.

---

By the way, your PRIMARY KEY Constraint could be a problem. Actually, it is a common situation when blocks are being replaced. So you should handle this situation.

Comment: Thank you a lot for detail answer. It seems a big issue with Cloudflare but sadly even I reported the issue on their support community but no one care about it.